# Where are the BCrypt NTSTATUS code return values defined?

Tags: c, windows, cng

The Windows [CNG Cryptographic Primitive Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa833130(v=vs.85).aspx) have return values of type `NTSTATUS`. Several possible (symbolic) return values are mentioned, for example `STATUS_AUTH_TAG_MISMATCH` for the [BCryptDecrypt function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375391(v=vs.85).aspx).

These symbols are not defined in `bcrypt.h`, nor in any other header file mentioned in the documentation. I can not use them in my code because they can not be resolved. Where are they located?

Comment: Also see [Compile errors when using C++ and bcrypt header](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57472787/608639). Apparently Microsoft forgt to include their own `<windows.h>` header in `<bcrypt.h>`. Microsoft screwed this up badly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are defined in:

```
ntstatus.h
```

Comment: Thanks, got it. When I include that file, I get lots of warnings though, like  `warning C4005: 'STATUS_WAIT_0' : macro redefinition`. The previous definition is in `winnt.h`, which gets included from `windows.h`. Am I supposed/allowed at all to include `ntstatus.h` directly?

Comment: I found the answer to my comment [here](http://www.mschaef.com/blog/tech/win32/windows_h_is_wierd.html), had to add `#define WIN32_NO_STATUS` and `#undef WIN32_NO_STATUS` around the `#include windows.h`. Maybe you can add that to your answer.

Comment: But not for some platforms; see [What header to include for an NTSTATUS when building for ARM platforms?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36963346)

Answer (score 0):

windows.h is redefining macros without checking. This works:

```
#include <ntstatus.h>
#define WIN32_NO_STATUS 1
#include <windows.h>
```